# Need to find a sequence formula to decrease 2 values depending on fixed values continuously

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find a sequence formula to decrease 2 values to fixed values continuously at nearly 250 steps

Therefore I am trying to decrease `"Def_Value"` based on `"Decrease_%"` and it should be at around 50 after 250 steps (`"Def_Value"` starts at 100).

`"Decrease_%"` starts at 2 and it should be 0 after 250 steps.

I used this formula `=SUM(C3-(C3*B3/100))` for `"Def_Value"` and I
am trying to get results like in the Table below:

| Sno | Decrease_% | Def_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.000000000 | 100.000000000 |
| 2 | 1.992000000 | 98.000000000 |
| 3 | 1.984000000 | 96.047840000 |
| 4 | ... | ... |
| 5 | ... | ... |
| 248 | 0.024000000 | 50.600000000 |
| 249 | 0.016000000 | 50.400000000 |
| 250 | 0.008000000 | 50.200000000 |
| 251 | 0.000000000 | 50.000000000 |
| 252 | 0.000000000 | 50.000000000 |
| 253 | 0.000000000 | 50.000000000 |
| 254 | 0.000000000 | 50.000000000 |

***But instead I am getting:***

| Sno | Decrease_% | Def_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.000000000 | 100.000000000 |
| 2 | 1.992000000 | 98.000000000 |
| 3 | 1.984000000 | 96.047840000 |
| 4 | ... | ... |
| 5 | ... | ... |
| 248 | 0.024000000 | 7.994176832 |
| 249 | 0.016000000 | 7.992258230 |
| 250 | 0.008000000 | 7.990979469 |
| 251 | 0.000000000 | 7.990340190 |
| 252 | 0.000000000 | 7.990340190 |

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What are the values in your columns "D" and "F"?
Is column "D" = "Sno" and "F" = "Def_value"?

Comment: only A.B,C is there A=SlNo, B=Decrease_%, C=Def_Value

Comment: What makes you think it will stop at 50? I got 7.990034 like you have.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are decreasing the values starting with 100 by a progressively decreasing percent of the **original value**.

It is WAY easier to decrease the values by a **fixed percent** of the values immediately above.

In **B1** enter 100.
In **B2** enter `=B1*$C$1`
In **B3** enter `=B2*$C$1`
and copy downwards through **B250**.

In **C1** enter a "guess", say 99.9%

You will notice that **B250** does not get down to the desired *50*

The final step is to use Solver to force **B250** to 50 by adjusting **C1**.

You should see:

[image]

[image]

Solver changed the 99.9% to 99.7220144035683%

and **B250** is extremely close to the desired 50.

Comment: In B1 enter 100,
In B2 enter ="=SUM(B1-C1)",
In B3 enter "0.2",
and copy downwards through B251,

it will be 50 at 251 step exactly But C1 should start from 2 and end with 0.